# how many records are required for classifier training in supervised learning

Tags: classification, data-science, supervised-learning

hi i m new in machine learning.i want to train a KNN-classifier with the dataset having fifty complete records(without missing values) and 103 incomplete records (including missing values)

i want to ask that is this dataset is defensible for the classification purpose. or should i search for some new dataset?

i m attaching some screenshots from my dataset.. POS is the label class in the dataset.

[screenshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL0yY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your feature space is of size `n`, i.e. no of input columns, than a `k*n`, where k >= 3, complete sample size should be a good amount of data to start with.

You can also look into imputing your data (missing values) with mean or any other extrapolation methods.

> One rough heuristic that is sometimes advocated is that the number of
>   data points should be no less than some multiple (say 5 or 10) of the
>   number of adaptive parameters in the model. - [Bishop, Page no. 9](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjV7sjH0bfUAhWKYVAKHc0NAngQFggvMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusers.isr.ist.utl.pt%2F~wurmd%2FLivros%2Fschool%2FBishop%2520-%2520Pattern%2520Recognition%2520And%2520Machine%2520Learning%2520-%2520Springer%2520%25202006.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEVQzQ_dEpxG4P7NamTWUXnVXzCng&sig2=wtC52OGzXFvzz50kPGdEIQ)

Comment: so you mean if my k= 3 and attributes (columns) = 5 then 3x5 = 15 records will be enough for classification purpose ?

Comment: yes! just to confirm, k is just an constant here and has nothing to do with the parameters of any algorithm (KNN_classifier in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Go for safe datasets like the default "iris dataset" provided by scikit learn itself
You can also search the UCI Machine Learning Repository for good datasets.

Comment: i have gone through UCI repository but there was no relevant dataset. i m working on "role detection in terrorist organization using supervised learning" .. can u suggest me some repository from which i get the data about the personal information of terrorist.. like education background, gender and role in organization (i.e leader or non leader)

Comment: I have no idea about where such dataset might exist. You might check into CS229 projects to get any idea about the project you are doing. I am pretty sure they might have projects related to this domain. Just search cs229 projects on terrorism